# WM_DEVICECHANGE comes twice when disconnecting/connecting device

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm listening in my message loop for WM_DEVICECHANGE, and when I remove or thrust my webcam, WM_DEVICECHANGE comes twice, with identical MSG (with same HWND, UINT, WPARAM and LPARAM). How to fix it?

Comment: What is the actual `wParam` value that is being duplicated? The value tells you how to interpret the `lParam` value, which will be a pointer to an event-specific struct containing more detailed information about the change. Are you looking at that detail at all?

Answer (score 5):

This is to be expected.  Although the wParam and lParam *should* be different to indicate a different stage of the device state change, it would not surprise me to know there are duplicate messages.

If I recall correctly, what we did in our code is that when we received a WM_DEVICECHANGE event is to do any of the following:

1. Once the first one came in, ignore all subsequent notifications for the next couple of seconds.
2. Or just use the WM_DEVICECHANGE as a hint and not the truth.  When we received such a message, we would re-enumerate the device list with the appropriate API and see if anything changed since the last time we enumerated.  If the new list was the same as the original list, then there was nothing to do.

Comment: Good suggestions, but why exactly are multiple messages to be expected?

Comment: Probably because a USB device is technically a composite of multiple devices. For example, a webcam is both a USB camera and a USB microphone.

Comment: You'd think even if the device was a composite of multiple devices you would still be able to distinguish between them through windows api in some way. If you wouldn't mind looking at my question, which is a similar question where I'm trying to limit these arrivals/removals in order to setup device communication faster. However, my problem is that my device can't seem to read data until these multiple arrivals/removals stop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655681/why-are-there-multiple-dbt-deviceremovecomplete-messages-for-a-ble-hid-device

Comment: It's been that way for a long time.  The odds of them fixing that anytime soon are nil.  For what it's worth, I literally had to deal with a similar issue the other day with regards to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`.  Change your Windows colors, and your window gets that message 5-10 times.